# Trasform a Dataframe 6x3 in a special array 9x2, choose the element of dataframe to store in an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

Data={'First':[1,2,3,4,5,5],'Second':[6,7,8,9,10,4],'Third':[0,1,0,1,0,100]}
df=DataFrame(Data,columns=['First','Second','Third'])
```

*Here there is an example of dataframe. The result that I want to store is:*

```
array([[  1,   4],
       [  6,   9],
       [  0,   1],
       [  2,   5],
       [  7,  10],
       [  1,   0],
       [  3,   5],
       [  8,   4],
       [  0, 100]])
```

*I'd like to choose the number of rows and columns of the array, using for example a for cycle. The script will be able to read each element of dataframe, for 2 or 3 rows, to store in a column of an array, then to restart from the last element +1 of dataframe, and to store in a second column of an array.*

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reshape and transpose the values:

```
np.transpose(df.values.reshape(2,9))
```

or with a nicer syntax (thanks to @AndyL. for noticing):

```
df.values.reshape(2,-1).T
```

gives:

```
array([[  1,   4],
       [  6,   9],
       [  0,   1],
       [  2,   5],
       [  7,  10],
       [  1,   0],
       [  3,   5],
       [  8,   4],
       [  0, 100]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: `df.values.reshape(2,-1).T`

Comment: @AndyL.: Thank you very much. Much nicer syntax. I have edited my post with it.

Comment: @AndreaPatierno: Please do not forget to accept one of the answers to tell future readers that you no longer need help on this question.

Answer (score 1):

breaking the array into two, using `np.flatten` to convert the 2D arrays into 1D, `np.newaxis` to increase the dimension and then using `np.hstack`to stack them horizontally

```
np.hstack((df[:3].values.flatten()[np.newaxis].T,df[3:].values.flatten()[np.newaxis].T))
```

**Output**

```
array([[  1,   4],
       [  6,   9],
       [  0,   1],
       [  2,   5],
       [  7,  10],
       [  1,   0],
       [  3,   5],
       [  8,   4],
       [  0, 100]], dtype=int64)
```